# SNMP4J set Error

Tags: java, snmp4j

I'm excuting this DOS snmp command set by snmp4J:

snmpset -c private -v 2c 192.168.1.26 .1.3.6.1.4.1.991.100.5.19.3.0 u 1

This is the code:

```
public class SnmpSetExample {

private static String ipAddress = "192.168.1.26";
private static String port = "161";
private static String sysContactOid = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.991.100.5.19.3.0";
private static int sysContactValue = 1;
private static int snmpVersion = SnmpConstants.version2c;
private static String community = "private";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("SNMP SET Demo");

    TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
    transport.listen();

    CommunityTarget comtarget = new CommunityTarget();
    comtarget.setCommunity(new OctetString(community));
    comtarget.setVersion(snmpVersion);
    comtarget.setAddress(new UdpAddress(ipAddress + "/" + port));
    comtarget.setRetries(2);
    comtarget.setTimeout(1000);

    PDU pdu = new PDU();

    // Setting the Oid and Value for sysContact variable
    OID oid = new OID(sysContactOid);

    Variable var = new Integer32(sysContactValue);
    VariableBinding varBind = new VariableBinding(oid, var);
    pdu.add(varBind);

    pdu.setType(PDU.SET);
    pdu.setRequestID(new Integer32(1));

    // Create Snmp object for sending data to Agent
    Snmp snmp = new Snmp(transport);

    ResponseEvent response = snmp.set(pdu, comtarget);

    if (response != null) {
        System.out.println("\nResponse:\nGot Snmp Set Response from Agent");
        PDU responsePDU = response.getResponse();

        if (responsePDU != null) {
            int errorStatus = responsePDU.getErrorStatus();
            int errorIndex = responsePDU.getErrorIndex();
            String errorStatusText = responsePDU.getErrorStatusText();

            if (errorStatus == PDU.noError) {
                System.out.println("Snmp Set Response = " + responsePDU.getVariableBindings());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: Request Failed");
                System.out.println("Error Status = " + errorStatus);
                System.out.println("Error Index = " + errorIndex);
                System.out.println("Error Status Text = " + errorStatusText);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: Response PDU is null");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error: Agent Timeout... ");
    }
    snmp.close();
}
```

}

But my error result is:

```
...
Response: 
Got Snmp Set Response from Agent 
Error: Response PDU is null
```

PDU is ready setted to .SET. Somebody know what's missing in the parameters or the code?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in: Variable var = new Integer32(sysContactValue);

Change Gauge32 or UnsignedInterger32 insted of Integer32 type. It is necessary to always check the data type of the value to send.